# Python suds length error

Tags: python, soap, cgi

I am currently trying to access a soap cgi interface with the python suds library.

```
client = Client("https://webhost/soap/soap.cgi",username='Theusername',password='mypassword')
```

I keep getting the error message

```
suds.transport.TransportError: HTTP Error 411: Length Required
```

I looked at a question similar to this, but only adding the length header manually. That is not working either. I have tried adding

```
headers={'Content-Length':200} and tried soapheaders={'Content-Length':200}
```

but still no luck.

Does suds not support cgi? The suds/wsdl.py library keeps trying to interpret the link and wsdl is not used anywhere on this host I am working with.

---

The fix for me was using the pysimplesoap library.

```
import httplib2
from pysimplesoap.client import SoapClient

client = SoapClient(
location = "https://webhost/soap/soap.cgi",
action = "<Directory of soap access module>#",
namespace = "<Directory of soap access module>",
soap_ns = 'soap',trace=true, username='user',password='pass')
```

The directory of the soap access module was relative to the root of the server. In my situation, the module was written in perl, but should work with any language as long as it is a soap module. This solution would be helpful for anyone translating a perl script using soap:lite to a python function.

I hope this helps someone else who runs into the same problem.

Sidenode: In order to add the username and password fields, I followed this post:

[here](https://code.google.com/p/pysimplesoap/issues/detail?id=113)

Also, the installation of httplib2 is necessary for pysimplesoap

Comment: what is the length of the document you send? Which code do you use to send the request? can you post the whole stack trace?

Comment: I have resolved this conflict. It turns out that using pysimplesoap was the solution.